# Stuck in starting gnome after installing gpu drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, gnome, graphics, amd-graphics

Recently installed lutris/wine so i can play my favorite games. After installing lutris it told me to install my gpu drivers. I followed this official guide https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers

I am on 18.04 and i have an intel and amd gpu
Intel hd 4000 and amd radeon 7670m,
so i executed these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```

After rebooting, my pc gets stuck at “starting Gnome Display Manager” and console freezes. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

reboot and right after the bios screen press shift ( if bios mode ) or esc ( if uefi mode )
that should bring up the grub manager 
choose advanced options and select basic display or press c to edit the primary boot line.
if editing the boot line add nomodeset right after quiet and splash. Press ctrl-x to boot.
Once at the desktop you can remove the proprietary driver.